# Docker images and containers disappear after daemon-reload

Tags: docker

I have created a proget container according to the official document like this:

```
docker run --name proget-sql \
      -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=123' \
      -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' --net=proget --restart=unless-stopped \
      -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

```
docker exec -it proget-sql /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd \
   -S localhost -U SA -P '123' \
   -Q 'CREATE DATABASE [ProGet] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
```

```
docker run -d \
    -v /data/proget/packages:/var/proget/packages \
    -p 80:80 \
    --net=proget \
    --name=proget \
    --restart=unless-stopped \
    -e SQL_CONNECTION_STRING='Data Source=proget-sql; Initial Catalog=ProGet; User ID=sa; Password=123' \
    proget.inedo.com/productimages/inedo/proget:5.3.18
```

And now we have a new harbor server instance so we add an insecure-registries in the /etc/docker/daemon.json . But after

```
systemctl daemon-reload;systemctl restart docker
```

the docker images and containers on the proget server all have been disappeared.Could you please tell me what is the reason and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. but after giving the below command (once or twice), i was able to see the images and containers
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" –SwitchDaemon